# Unable to understand the Node Express various API

Tags: node.js, express, post, postman

I am new and learning Node Express with MongoDB 4.0 from various onlines sources. When I go through two different tutorials, I messed up with its different coding style.

**Tutorial 1** : [Callicoder Tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/node-js-express-mongodb-restful-crud-api-tutorial/)

**Tutorial 2** : [Academind Tutorial](https://github.com/academind/node-restful-api-tutorial/tree/09-image-upload)

I am confusing on the following topics in the both tutorials.

```
+--+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|# |       Tutorial 1          |       Tutorial 2          |      Clarification        |
|  |      (Callicoder)         |       (Academind)         |                           |
+--+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|1 |  Can not upload images    |  Can upload images        |  Why can't in Callicoder? |
+--+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|2 |  One .js file (server.js) |  server.js and app.js     | Why two files in Academind|
+--+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|3 |  POST method using        |  POST method using        |Difference of POST methods,|
|  |   router.post             |   exports.create          |What means 'exports.create'|
+--+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|4 |  Use two parameters       | Use three parameters      | Why three in image upload |
+--+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|5 | Using params in Postman   |Using form-data in POstman |  How they are different   |
+--+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

**Code snipperts of Callicoder**

```
const express= require("express");
const multer = require('multer');
const User = require('../models/user.model.js');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens


// POST
exports.create = ("/",(req, res, next) => 
{
    var varName= req.query.name;
    var varUname = req.body.username;
    var varPass = req.body.password;
    var varEmail = req.body.email;
    console.log(varName)

    const user = new User(
        {
            name: varName, //required
            address: req.body.address, 
            logo: req.body.logo, 
            username: varUname,  //required
            password: varPass,   //required
            phone_number: req.body.phone_number, 
            email: varEmail,  //required
            token_key : token
    });

    // Save Programe in the database
    user.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.send(
            {
                "error_message": [],
                "results":"User created successfully",
                "status": "Success",
                "token": token
            });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            error_message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Programe."
        });
    });
});
```

**Code snippets of Academind**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require('multer');
const Product = require("../models/product");

//file storage code
// file filter code for jpg and png
// file upload code

router.post('/', upload.single('productImage'), (req, res, next) => {
  const product = new Product({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.query.name,
      price: req.query.price,
      productImage: req.file.path
  });
  product.save().then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
          message: 'Created product successfully',
          createdProduct: {
              name: result.name,
              price: result.price,
              _id: result._id,
              request: {
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: 'http://localhost:3000/products/${result._id}'
              }
          }
      });
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
          error: err
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the actual code you're asking about by pasting it into your question and formatting it appropriately as code?

Comment: @jfriend00, Please see the added code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of Express as an incredibly lightweight and basic framework that's very closely wrapped around the core of NodeJS. Most of the problems you're having aren't Express specific, they're just different npm packages that extend or alter the core functionality.

1. The way that the data is parsed by the application matters. Academind can handle image uploads because it uses the `multer` package. This is a middleware that handles any requests done with the `multipart/form-data` encoding type, which is how images are sent to the server. Expected encoding types are also the answer to #5.
2. The two files are just personal preference. You can do everything in one file, but many people like to require the `app.js` in their `server.js` to further separate the "duties" of each file.
3. This is similar to above, how they're separating the duties of the files even further. If you look closely, both are eventually ending up being called with the router. By creating Controller files in one of the projects they're separating whats called the "business logic" from the route definitions. It does the same thing, but some consider it more organized.
4. Are the two parameters vs three parameters `req, res, next`? If so, those are actually available for every single route in express. A lot of the time you don't need `next` in your code so programmers will just leave it out.
5. This comes back to the expected encoding type of your request. Various middleware will handle and allow different encoding-types as needed. https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser is probably the most popular one as it's built into expressjs. This is how it interprets the requests you make and sets the req.body object. The "params" type actually sets the values as part of the url, appending them like so: 127.0.0.1:3000?param1=test&param2=test. Where form-data is a part of the request that's being made and isn't available as a get parameter.

I hope this helps make more sense for you!

Edit: Based on your comment below, NodeJS functions using a lot of different middleware. Theoretically you could do this any number of times if you want to, and just keep using next to go to the next function in the middleware.

Ex:

```
app.get('/', 
   (req, res, next) => {
       // do something
       next()
   },
   (req, res, next) => {
       // this part runs when next is called
       // do something
       next()
   },
   (req, res, next) => {
       if (1==x) {
          res.send()
       } else {
          const err = new Error('Error');
          // sends to error handling middleware
          next(err);
       }
   });
```

Comment: for the answer 4, please see the added code snippets, the callicoder has two parameters `exports.create = ("/",(req, res, next) => ` and the Academind has three parameters `router.post('/', upload.single('productImage'), (req, res, next) => `

Comment: Ahh, those are considered middleware! I'll update my other post with more info.

Comment: Thank you so much @JacobW, Nice explanations.

Comment: please mark the question as answered if the explanations helped you :)